# Convert <div> to <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container div which has a couple of other divs:

```
<div class='container'>
 <div>one</div>
 <div>two</div>
 <div>three</div>
 <div>four</div>
</div>
```

I would like to change all the divs in the container div to ps, so that it looks like:

```
 <div class='container'>
 <p>one</p>
 <p>two</p>
 <p>three</p>
 <p>four</p>
</div>
```

How can i accomplish this through jquery? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** 
I apologize for the lack of clarity, to be precise, i have more than one div container, each of which has other divs inside of it. I don't think the answers already provided will only change the divs contained by div container, but will change all the divs:

```
<!--block one-->
 <div class='container'>
 <div>one</div>
 <div>two</div>
 <div>three</div>
 <div>four</div>
</div>

 <!--block two-->
  <div class='container'>
 <div>one</div>
 <div>two</div>
 <div>three</div>
 <div>four</div>
</div>

  <!--block three-->
  <div class='container'>
 <div>one</div>
 <div>two</div>
 <div>three</div>
 <div>four</div>
</div>
```

and so on. what i need is that only the divs inside the div class container are changed into p's:

```
  <div class='container'>
   <p>one</p>
   <p>two</p>
   <p>three</p>
   <p>four</p>
  </div>


 <div class='container'>
   <p>one</p>
   <p>two</p>
   <p>three</p>
   <p>four</p>
  </div>
```

there's a small plugin to do it,:

```
  (function($) {
   $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
    var attrs = {};

    $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
        attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
    });

    this.replaceWith(function() {
        return $(\"<\" + newType + \"/>\", attrs).append($(this).contents());
     });
     }
     })(jQuery);
```

to use:

```
$(\"div\").changeElementType(\"p\");
```

But won't doing that change all the divs to ps? How would i modify it to target only the divs inside the div in class container? Thank you.

Comment: I have to ask... Why? Either replace the original HTML source, or apply some CSS to `#container>div` to add margins.

Answer (score 5):

You can't really change the tagName, but you can replace the existing divs with p's:

```
$('.container').children('div').each(function(e, el) {
    $(el).replaceWith( $('<p />', {text: $(this).text()}) );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pumfh/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
    $('.container > div').each(function() {
        $(this).contents().wrapAll("<p>").parent().unwrap();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

it would be easy if you press *Contrl F* and open up the finding tool and then click find and replace type "`<div>`" on the find and "`<p>`" on the replace and then go through the ones u want and hit replace then it would be done easily without any errors :)

Comment: +1 There's always that. :) This *does* seem like the better approach...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".container").children("div").replaceWith(function(){

   return $("<p />").append($(this).contents());

});
```